# Alpine JS - Error : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_x_refs')

Tags: javascript, html, alpine.js

Hi I am using CDN link for alpine: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/alpinejs/3.9.0/cdn.min.js'

and I did this

And in live server I am getting this error in console:
[Check Screenshot for error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHGys.png)

Please tell me what is the issue.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_x_refs')
    at Function.Xr.inline (cdn.min.js:5:32320)
    at u (cdn.min.js:5:1964)
    at cdn.min.js:5:4403
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at cdn.min.js:5:4392
    at M (cdn.min.js:5:3335)
    at cdn.min.js:5:4361
    at Xt (cdn.min.js:5:1687)
    at S (cdn.min.js:5:4353)
    at cdn.min.js:5:3723
Xr.inline @ cdn.min.js:5
u @ cdn.min.js:5
(anonymous) @ cdn.min.js:5
(anonymous) @ cdn.min.js:5
M @ cdn.min.js:5
(anonymous) @ cdn.min.js:5
Xt @ cdn.min.js:5
S @ cdn.min.js:5
(anonymous) @ cdn.min.js:5
(anonymous) @ cdn.min.js:1
Je @ cdn.min.js:1
```

The code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/alpinejs/3.9.0/cdn.min.js'
        integrity='sha512-91GIHlafcLQRUuQqlBCEF/qOecSTcBkSsaPWP3jgstLpwZ8orjgDlPgJshIq+x9t8wFcrGEjUKSMRN3K5ibq6Q=='
        crossorigin='anonymous'></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/2.2.19/tailwind.min.css"
        integrity="sha512-wnea99uKIC3TJF7v4eKk4Y+lMz2Mklv18+r4na2Gn1abDRPPOeef95xTzdwGD9e6zXJBteMIhZ1+68QC5byJZw=="
        crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
</head>
<body>
    <header x-ref="header">
        header code here
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please provide some code you've used and information on what you've tried so far.

Comment: @TimLangner kindly check editing my post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add the [`x-data` attribute](https://alpinejs.dev/directives/data#data-less-components) to an Alpine.js component even without any data definitions, otherwise Alpine.js will ignore it.

```
<header x-data="{}" x-ref="header">
    header code here
</header>
```

Also add the `defer` attribute to Alpine.js `<script>` tag or move it t the end of `<body>` to solve the warning message.

Comment: Thank You it worked but can you tell why x-data?

Comment: The `x-` is the Alpine.js specific prefix for Alpine.js directives (other JS frameworks uses different one, e.g. Vue.js has `v-` prefix). With `x-data` you can define an Alpine.js component and create some local variables for it. Alpine.js is a "minimal" framework, so we have to mark a component explicitly. Btw don't forget to accept the answer.